# Unable to boot Ubuntu 12.04 live CD

Tags: 12.04, installation, live-usb, live-cd

I am unable to boot from an Ubuntu installation disk. When I try to boot, it starts Windows automatically.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 live CD.

Comment: You need to unable the 'BOOT from CD-DVD DRIVE' from your BIOS setting , which normally can be accessed  at the startup of your System. Also make sure , that the ISO image is properly written on the CD.

Comment: hi excuse me, I am unable to boot into ubuntu without my usb, I have to have it plugged into my computer if I want to run ubuntu, please help.

Comment: Do you mean , you have installed ubuntu , but it only runs when you plug your USB Drive to your computer.Or You have Ubuntu Live USB Drive.

Answer (score 1):

You want to boot from USB Drive.

Read here http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000192.htm

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reconfigure your BIOS to boot from CD/USB first. To do so, press CTRL+ALT+DELETE, F1, SHIFT+DELETE, or whatever your POST screen says to go to BIOS setup and reconfigure. Alternatively you can press F12, ESC, or whatever, again the POST screen, tells you to choose boot order temporarily. Choose the CD drive contains your Ubuntu CD (or USB drive). Remember if you configure your computer BIOS carelessly you may brick your computer.